# For $a = \frac{p^{q^r} - 1}{p^{q^{r-1}} - 1}$ and $q \mid a$, $q \mid (p^{q^{r-1}} - 1)$ imply that $q^{2}\nmid a$.

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, binomial-coefficients

Let $p,q$ be primes and $r \in \Bbb {N}$ and consider $a = \frac{p^{q^r} - 1}{p^{q^{r-1}} - 1}$. I have to show the following:

> Given $q \mid a$ and $q \mid (p^{q^{r-1}} - 1)$ I have to prove that $q^{2}\nmid a$.

Note that $a = \frac{p^{q^r} - 1}{p^{q^{r-1}} - 1} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q-1} {q \choose {j+1}} (p^{q^{r-1}} - 1)^j$ by the identity $ \frac{(1 + X)^q - 1}{X} = \sum\limits_{j=0}^{q-1} {q \choose j+1} X^{j}$. It is clear that $a>q$, hence there is the possibility of $q^2$ being a factor of $a$. I can't see any contradiction directly from the expression. I need some help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that $q\mid \binom{q}{2}$. Therefore, thanks to your last formula, $$a=q+(p^{q^{r-1}}-1)qk,$$
for some $k\in \mathbb Z$. Moreover $q\mid (p^{q^{r-1}}-1)$. We conclude that,
$$a=q+q^2s,$$
for some $s\in \mathbb Z$, and thus, $q^2\nmid a$ as wished.